# Simple HTML DOM PHP - Scrape Data from DIV with same class names

Tags: php, html, dom, scrape

I'm tying to scrape some data from a website for a back-end email that will be sent to a technician - the website user wont see this scraped data. - saves the tech clicking links if I can just present all the data in one page

my problem is the website I would like to scrape uses multiple classes with the same names.
the data i want to extract is highlighted on the image  (ideally each attached to its own variable) i.e.. $make, $model, etc

so far I have the below code that gets me to the section I need, but need a little help getting further.
I've manage to get the parent DIV to disply (the only one with a unique name)

any help or pointed (tutorials) in the right direction would be apricated. - I've looked at quite a few tutorials but none cover multiple classes with the same names, my guess is it's mastering the DOM Structure?
source html to scrape: view-source:https://www.rapidcarcheck.co.uk/results?RegPlate=rj02+kro

```
 include('simple_html_dom.php');

$Use_input = "XO10GEE"; //this will be submitted by user
$myUrl = "https://www.rapidcarcheck.co.uk/results?RegPlate=$Use_input";
$html = file_get_html($myUrl);

$div = $html->find('.vc_custom_1549901010336', 0)->parent();
echo $div;
```

[image]

Comment: You can master any DOM that you control. Anyone else's you should expect to change at any given moment and your code will break. You basically have to make semi-arbitrary decisions. You can walk nodes and sometimes it will work, and other times edge cases will freak things out. For debugging, write each unique scrape to disk so that you have a pool to work from in the future. Sometimes you just have to accept too much data, too, and tell your users to accept that, too.

Comment: If you know exactly which elements you want, one hacky way would be to use `:nth-child` selector. Keeping in mind Chris Haas's comment though

Comment: Thanks guys, I've gone down the hacky route for now. $div = $html->find('.wpb_wrapper', 24); but for the info i need the UK government now offer an api.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?